# Variable Length Slice in List Comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, slice

Suppose I have a numpy array of step sizes, `N`, and a set of variables `V` of length `np.sum(N)`. For example:

```
N = np.array([2,3,2])
V = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7])
```

Preferably using list comprehension, how do I slice `V` such that the result is a list of lists, split by the steps in N?

For example:

```
foo(V, N)
> [[0.1,0.2], [0.3, 0.4,0.5], [0.6,0.7]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy has a [`split()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) function that will give you unequal arrays. It wants indices rather than lengths. You can do this with `cumsum()` and just ignore the last empty value (or leftovers if you don't account for the whole list).

```
N = np.array([2,3,2])
V = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7])

np.split(V, N.cumsum())[:-1]
# [array([0.1, 0.2]), array([0.3, 0.4, 0.5]), array([0.6, 0.7])]
```

Comment: Split turned out to be a much superior answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
Vi = iter(V)
[[next(Vi) for _ in range(n)] for n in N]
# [[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4, 0.5], [0.6, 0.7]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem using itertools.islice:

```
    def UnequalDivide(self, iterable, chunks):
        it = iter(iterable)
        return [list(islice(it, c)) for c in chunks]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do that with regular lists and slices:

```
N = [2,3,2]
V = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]

def foo(N,V):
    n, lst = 0, []
    for i,v in enumerate(N, 1):
        lst.append(V[n:n+v])
        n += v
    return lst

print(foo(N,V))
```

Output:

```
[[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4, 0.5], [0.6, 0.7]]
```

---

---

---

You can do the same with numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

N = np.array([2,3,2])
V = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7])

def foo(N,V):
    n, lst = 0, []
    for i,v in enumerate(N, 1):
        lst.append(V[n:n+v].tolist())
        n += v
    return lst

print(foo(N,V))
```

Output:

```
[[0.1, 0.2], [0.3, 0.4, 0.5], [0.6, 0.7]]
```